# Flink Context vs TriggerContext

Tags: java, design-patterns, apache-flink

### Background

To maintain a state, [Trigger](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#triggers) uses `TriggerContext` while the [window functions](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#window-functions) uses `Context`. Although logically similar, `TriggerContext` and `Context` do not seem to share the same code (neither through inheritance nor usage).

### Question

Why do `TriggerContext` and `Context` don't share the same code and have a different usage pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two classes are the just the tip of the iceberg; Flink's APIs make frequent use of this Context object pattern. The objective here is to provide user-defined functions with just the information they need, while avoiding any unnecessary coupling between components.